# Can Flash load a Flex mx:module created in Flex Builder 4

Tags: flash, apache-flex, module, loading

I have a Flex module created in Flash Builder 4 as a swf file. I am trying to load and run in within a Flash application. I can get the module loaded but I can not get the flash application to access any module functions. Here is how I load the module in Flash and the error I get. If I change the module to an application type swf then it loads and runs but now I have two applications on top of each other. I would like the loaded module swf to be able to have access the Flash stage object.

ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property application not found on MyModule__mx_core_FlexModuleFactory and there is no default value.

```
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
addChild(loader);
loader.load(new URLRequest("MyModule.swf"), new LoaderContext(false, ApplicationDomain.currentDomain));
loader.addEventListener("mx.managers.SystemManager.isBootstrapRoot", systemManagerHandler);
loader.addEventListener("mx.managers.SystemManager.isStageRoot", systemManagerHandler);
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,loadIt);

 function loadIt(e:Event):void
 {  
        var myclip:MovieClip = loader.content as MovieClip;
        trace(myclip.info());
    if(myclip.application == null )
          myclip.addEventListener("applicationComplete", onAppComplete );
         }
 }
 function onAppComplete(e:Event):void
 {
    var myclip:MovieClip = loader.content as MovieClip;
    trace("appComplete");
  }
```

Comment: When you say Module are you using the word generically, or are you talking about a Flex app based off MX:Module?

Comment: The title is a bit misleading. Flex module is not the same thing as an AS3 module - if such thing even exists...

Answer (score 2):

Flex Modules must be loaded by Flex application SWFs. They cannot be loaded by non-Flex SWFs.

You should use a Module in Flex to load a part of your application after the main app has loaded, which I understand is a use-case outside of Flex too. However, the Module needs the rest of the application to be present because it omits many core classes from the Flex framework that should already be present in the main Flex application SWF.